# Unable to enter chat room

Tags: firefox

When I try to enter a chat room on Tor that I easily enter using any other regular browser I get the notification: Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at... is there a simple way I can get around this?

Thanks

Comment: It's possible the site doesn't allow access from Tor, there would be no way to get around it from Tor alone in that case. You should contact the site adminstrators to find out more, we can't answer definitively why it's happening with the information available.

Comment: The site doesn't allow Tor because of previous abuse by Tor users. That is a shame but obviously there can be no control on who uses Tor.

Comment: However, I was given this suggestion as a compromise: Use whitelisting magnachat.com, accesses to port 8080, or the magnachat.com IP address... but this is way above my knowledge and if it can be simplified and directions attached it would certainly be good.